# How do I append a value to the version when the installer executes, for an installer built with Install4j?

Tags: java, installation, install4j

We have a Java application that is installed with an installer built with Install4j. The product accesses different database tiers depending on where it is installed. So the development tier is installed at C:....\dev\ProductName, the test tier is installed at C:....\test\ProductName, etc.

In addition, the sysadmins want the program to append the database tier to the version number, so they can query the registry to see what version is installed for a particular tier. So, version 1.5.0 would become 1.5.0.dev.

Is there a way to append something to the version when the installer runs? So far I have not been able to make installers do this. I have tried running a script that sets the "sys.version" variable, adding a ${tier} variable to the version field, and a few other things, but have not been able to make the version change when the installer runs. Maybe that is just not possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append a string to the installation directory at runtime, add a "Run script" action to the "Startup" node of the installer and call

```
context.setInstallationDirectory(
     new File(context.getInstallationDirectory(), ".dev1"));
```

in it. On "Installer->Update Options", the "Detect previous installation directory" check box should be deselected, otherwise the added strings will accumulate during updates.

Comment: Thank you. This works for the installation directory. Is there a way to append to the version or product name?

Comment: You can override messages that display the product name or the version, but the version itself cannot be changed at runtime.

Comment: Ok, we will stop trying to change the version then. :-) How do we change the product name at runtime? I don't see a setter for in in the context.

Comment: Changing the application name is possible by using an installer variable in the "Full name" field on the General Settings->Application Info step, such as `${installer:myProductName}`. You can then use a "Set a variable" action in the "Startup" node of the Installer to set it. Also, you should pre-configure this variable with a default value on the "Installer variables" tab for the installer.

Comment: Hey, getting much closer! The only problem now is that when the installer launches, it says "${installer:myProductName} is preparing the install4j Wizard which will guide you....". That doesn't change when I supply -VmyProductName=xxxx on the command line, so it seems to be set at compile time. Any way to fix this?

Comment: The native part of the installer cannot replace installer variables. You can override this message on the General Settings->Languages step with a custom localization file in which you override `PrepareInstaller=Your custom message`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Everything is working and the products owners are happy.